# Class type non-type template parameter initialization does not compile

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++20

EDIT: this question is three years old, how can it be a duplicate of another one asked Yesterday???

I was under the impression that the following should become valid code under the new C++20 standard:

```
struct Foo
{
  int a, b;
};

template<Foo>
struct Bar
{};

Bar<{.a=1, .b=2}> bar;
```

Yet, `gcc 10.2.0`, with `-std=c++20` set complains: `could not convert ‘{1, 2}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Foo’` and Clang cannot compile this snippet either. Can someone point out why it is not well formed?

Comment: This example program is accepted by GCC 11 and MSVC 19.28, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tfn4bcaaY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This template-argument

```
{.a=1, .b=2}
```

is not allowed according to the grammar for a [template-argument](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument) which only allows the following constructs:

> template-argument:
>
> > constant-expression
> >
> > type-id
> >
> > id-expression

A brace-init list is not any of the above constructs, it's actually an [initializer](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#nt:initializer) and so it cannot be used as a template-argument.

You can be explicit about the type of the object that you use as the template-argument:

```
Bar<Foo{.a=1, .b=2}> bar;
```

and this will work, since this is a constant-expression.

Comment: That does compile, but I don't understand why the compiler is unable to make the deduction here and is perfectly fine with `bar({.a=1, .b=2})` when `bar` is a function that takes an argument of type `Foo`. Can you explain why the deduction is not possible here?

Comment: See if `auto&& ref = {.a = 1, .b = 2};` compiles. Template argument type deduction and `auto&&` type deduction follow the same rules. I imagine it won't compile either and you'll have an easier time figuring out why that is so..

Comment: @TanveerBadar I'm not convinced. In OP's case there's nothing to deduce, there are no unknown types.

Comment: @Peter That's a good question, it's not obvious to me, I'll have to think about it. Could you edit your question to ask that explicitly?

Comment: Theory: a template argument must be an expression, and `{.a=1, .b=2}` isn't one.

Comment: Seems like it's just the c++ grammar that disallows it: https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument-list is what a template argument is, and a `braced-init-list` is an [initializer](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#nt:braced-init-list), not a constant expression.

Comment: @Artyer That seems reasonable, but I can't seem to find exactly why `brace-init-list` is not a constant-expression.

Comment: @cigien: Because braced-init-lists are *never* expressions.

Comment: @Peter I edited the answer. It's not a deduction thing, but just a limitation of the grammar.

Comment: This is CWG2450; expect it to be fixed, presumably even with `-std=c++20`, in a few months (plus or minus implementation time).

Comment: @DavisHerring: Aha, that's very interesting, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

It's a C++ grammar thing. Things used for template arguments must be [either type-ids, id-names, or constant-expressions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#nt:template-argument).

And a braced-init-list is not an expression of any kind. They can only grammatically be present in a small number of places, specifically those used to initialize an object or variable.

In the past, it wasn't really relevant, since there wasn't much reason to use a braced-init-list to initialize the few valid NTTPs. Obviously that's changed, so this is something of an oversight. But this is what the C++20 standard says.