# Valid brace initialization for template non-type template parameter in C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20, list-initialization

Consider the template `S` and `f` with non-type template parameter `int`:

```
template <int> struct S {};
template <int> void f() {}
```

GCC rejects the brace initialization for template non-type template parameter in C++17 mode since template argument is not allowed according to the [grammar for a template-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64703505/class-type-non-type-template-parameter-initialization-does-not-compile):

```
S<{}> s;
f<{}>();
```

but surprisingly, it [accepts](https://godbolt.org/z/EjPKsq) in C++20 mode. What changes in C++20?

Comment: [According to Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Kobbza), nothing changed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. Yep, but MSVC did the [same](https://godbolt.org/z/xv83jW) behavior. Maybe is that some extension prepare for the C++23?