# Struct non-type template parameter + agregate initialization: standard in c++20 or not

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

The following snippet extracted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64703505/class-type-non-type-template-parameter-initialization-does-not-compile) compiles with some recent gcc and msvc, but not with the latest clang.

Will it end compiling with clang, or is it some non-standard stuff that some compilers accept and other don't?

Thanks!

```cpp
struct Foo
{
  int a, b;
};

template<Foo>
struct Bar
{};

Bar<{.a=1, .b=2}> bar;
```

At this time with clang one has to do this to get it compiled:

```cpp
Bar<Foo{.a=1, .b=2}> bar;
```

Comment: Your link links to nothing.

Comment: It's probably a parsing bug in clang.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It may not be. Are braced-init-lists allowed as template arguments?

Answer (score 4):

This is [CWG 2450](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2450.html):

> Since non-type template parameters can now have class types, it would seem to make sense to allow a braced-init-list as a template-argument, but the grammar does not permit it.

This *should* work `Bar<{.a=1, .b=2}>` but is currently rejected by the grammar, which has not yet been updated to actually make this work.