# Program using class non type template parameter accepted by gcc but rejected by clang

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

I am learning C++ using the resources listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, I have [learnt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72963126/12002570) that in C++20 we can have a class type as a non type template parameter. Now, to better understand the concept, I tried the following example that is accepted by msvc and gcc but rejected by clang. **My question is** which compiler is right?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mb3qbvvPz)

```
struct Impl
{
  constexpr Impl(std::initializer_list<int>)
  {
      
  }
};
struct Bar{};
template<typename T, Impl impl>
struct Foo
{
    
};
int main()
{
    constexpr Foo<Bar, {1,2,3,4}> foo; //works in msvc & gcc but rejected in clang
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GCC and MSVC seems wrong.

Comment: `constexpr Foo<Bar, Impl{1,2,3,4}> foo;` works with all of the compilers in the link.  My guess is clang isn't performing the conversion and requires it to be explicit.  Not sure if that is the correct behavior or not.

Comment: I know that `constexpr Foo<Bar, Impl{1,2,3,4}> foo;` works but i am not asking about that. I want to know whether `constexpr Foo<Bar, {1,2,3,4}> foo;` is valid.

Comment: All __3__ compilers reject the code - live - https://godbolt.org/z/az5f68T9G

Comment: @RichardCritten Not if you compile against C++20 which is required for this: https://godbolt.org/z/jeT7Ydb3r.  Only clang fails that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, as non type template parameter require c++20.

Comment: @NathanOliver when I posted the question was tagged C++17 ... sorry about that.

Comment: @ user17732522 The [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470692/struct-non-type-template-parameter-agregate-initialization-standard-in-c20) is related but does not answer this question because the dupe only says that *the grammar does not allow braced init list* but it does not says which exact grammar/clause/rule the user is talking about. Note also that this question is with`language-lawyer` unlike the dupe.

Answer (score 2):

**GCC and MSVC are wrong** in accepting the program as it is ill-formed for the reason explained below.

The standard doesn't allow braced init list `{1,2,3,4}` to be a template argument. This can be seen from [temp.names#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.names#1):

> ```
> template-argument:
>     constant-expression
>     type-id
>     id-expression
> ```

And since `{1,2,3,4}` is not any of the above three listed constructs, it cannot be used as a template argument.

Additionally note that `{1,2,3,4}` **is not an expression** and does not have a type.

This is the reason clang generates the error saying:

```
       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
error: expected expression
    constexpr Foo<Bar, {1,2,3,4}> foo;
```

---

The gcc bug has been reported as:

[GCC accepts invalid program involving {1,2,3,4} as template argument](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106629)

And msvc bug as:

[MSVC accepts invalid program involving {1,2,3,4} as template argument](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-program-involving-/10120467)

Comment: Are you sure `{1,2,3,4}` isn't covered by `constant-expression`?  It doesn't seem to run afoul of any of the conditions [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#5) for a core constant expression.

Comment: @NathanOliver `{1,2,3,4}` is not even an expression so i don't think it qualifies for a `constant expression`. Does it?

Comment: This is CWG2450; GCC/MSVC are simply preemptively allowing the syntax.

Comment: Aha, looks like you need `type braced-init-list` in order for it to qualify as an expression.

Comment: @DavisHerring Can you give a link to CWG2450 in your last comment?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yup, that will be the same as `new-type { expression-list(optional) }` as point 3 listed here: [Explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: Link to CWG2450: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2450